# Is there any er diagram tool in Windows that I can use to connect to a MySQL 4.1 database in Unix?

Tags: mysql, windows, unix, cross-platform, erd

I have a few test databases in some Unix SUSE 8 servers and initially the plan was to find some tools which can directly create the [ERD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model) straight from the server until someone told me that I can find tools to connect from the Windows PC straight to the Unix MySQL database.

So I saw MySQL query analyzer which can do this but unfortunately there are no options to create an ERD. So are there any tools, preferably open source or free which can do this?

I've done some basic googling but didn't know what is the exact terms to use to search for this and have so far found nothing useful yet.

### Updates:

I just found out that the latest version of workbench doesn't work MySQL 4.1 Enterprise Edition which is the version that I have!

And I try to use [fabFORCE DBDesigner](http://www.fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/) but I can't even connect at all using that one :(
What can work for this version of MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the server is running in another platform is entirely irrelevant. It's MySQL, you talk MySQL and the MySQL Server will read you, the rest are details.

About the tool, I like the [MySQL GUI Tools](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/) package and [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.1.html), it's all you need to manage your MySQL stuff.

Comment: @Havenard, then i guess what i'm missing here are the steps on how to connect/setup. any ideas? thanks

Comment: You give the tools the IP address of the server, a user name, password and off you go. What are the problems you're having ?

Answer (score 1):

[DBDesigner](http://www.fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/) will do for MySQL 4.1.

This tool is the predecessor of [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.1.html). From my practical experience DBDesigner is a handy and user-friendly but so-so reliable tool (so save often!)

Comment: @Mao, i've just installed the windows workbench, and i don't know how to set it up, any tutorials or guide for this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Aqua data studio](http://aquafold.com/) can do that, IMO pretty well.